# Prove generalized fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I need to prove the following generalized version of the FTC but I'm unsure how this is even different to the 'non-generalized' FTC.

> Let $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and piecewise continuously differentiable. Then $\int_a^b F'(x) dx=F(b)-F(a)$.

I don't know how to prove the FTC so how should I proceed with this?

Comment: The FTC requires $F$ to be continuously differentiable. Here you're asked to relax this hypothesis to piecewise continuously differentiable. Can you use the FTC? Do you know the definition of 'piecewise continuosly differentiable'?

Comment: So $F$ is continuous and there exists a partition where $F$ is continuously differentiable on each interval of the partition. Is that right? I don't know whether I can use the FTC, if we can I still don't know where to start

Comment: That is right. Now just use the FTC on each interval and the fact that $\displaystyle \int \limits_a^bF'$ equals the finite sum of those 'small' integrals.